# Can Azure Static Web App pull an image from Azure Container Registry?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I Know Azure SWP is for static web applications, but can I deploy a containerized image to it?

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Azure Static Web Apps is used to build and deploy full stack web apps from code.
Like HTML, CSS, JS or GitHub images.
To deploy a container you must use Azure App Service.
With Azure App Service you can use Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?tabs=azure-cli&pivots=container-linux

Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).